# How to handle backend errors from Node/Koa on frontend apollo-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, koa, apollo

My frontend, using `apollo-client`, throws an exception when the backend returns an error after a request.

When the node server receives a request, I check the validity of the request's token using `koa` middleware. If the token is valid, the request is forwarded to the next middleware. If the token is invalid, I want to return a 401 access denied error to the client. To do this, I followed Koa's error documentation [located here](https://github.com/koajs/koa/wiki/Error-Handling).

The code for the error handling middleware I wrote:

```
function userIdentifier() {
  return async (ctx, next) => {
    const token = ctx.request.headers.authorization

    try {
      const payload = checkToken(token)
      ctx.user = {
        id: payload.userId,
        exp: payload.exp,
        iat: payload.iat,
      }
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.user = undefined
      ctx.throw(401, "access_denied")
      // throw new Error("access_denied")
    }

    await next()
  }
}
```

This seemingly works on the backend, but not on the frontend. When the frontend receives this error, a JavaScript runtime error occurs. I am not sure what causes this.

[image]

*Note, the unexpected "a" is the same "a" found in `ctx.throw(401, "access_denied")`. If it were instead `ctx.throw(401, "x")` the frontend shows "unexpected token x" instead.*

The frontend code where the errors happens:

[image]

In an attempt to fix this, I followed [Apollo's error handling documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html) and used `apollo-link-error`.

```
const errorLink = onError(props => {
  const { graphQLErrors, networkError } = props
  console.log("ON ERROR", props)
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
      )
    )
  if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`)
})
```

Then I combine all links and create the Apollo client like this:

```
const link = ApolloLink.from([errorLink, authLink, httpLink])

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

The output of the debugging `log` in `apollo-link-error` is as follows:

[image]

***Related Documents***

Someone seems to be having an [identical error](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2741), but a solution was not listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the errors were handled correctly on the frontend when I began using this library on the backend: https://github.com/jeffijoe/koa-respond

Using just `ctx.unauthenticated()`

But I would still like to know more about how to return json/object-based errors with koa without a plugin helping